# Check for wildcard in fish shell arguments

Tags: shell, fish

In writing a function for fish shell I want to know if a lone wildcard (not part of a bigger expression) was used in the command arguments. Fish does the wildcard expansion before passing arguments to my function, so there is no easy way that I can see to do that, aside from check whether the arguments are the same as the output of `ls`. The inefficiency of that method makes me sad, though. Is there a better way to do this, without going into fish's source code?

---

EDIT:
Thanks for the input. Specifically, I am looking to add some functionality like zshell has for warning if there is a `*` in the arguments of `rm`. I know that there was an issue opened on GitHub specifically about this but I couldn't find the link again. I have typod, for example, `rm * .o` instead of `rm *.o`, and accidentally deleted all my code (... which I brought back from git, but still).

---

EDIT 2:
Here is the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1511

Comment: In general, the appropriate thing to do is to make it the caller's burden to quote any wildcard against expansion and flag it appropriately -- how `find` has `-name`, for instance, which -- among other things -- says "this next argument is a wildcard". Explicit is better than implicit; the more you try to infer intent, the more potential there is to do the Wrong Thing.

Comment: You can use `rm -I` (capital `i`) with GNU `rm`. This will ask you *once* for confirmation if you're trying to remove more than three files or used `-r`. This option is not portable to other `rm` implementations though.

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker. I am aware of that option, but I don't think it accomplishes what I want -- whether I want to actually delete files or it was an accident is not really correlated with whether there are >3 of them.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way for a function to tell where its arguments came from. Maybe if you give more details about what you're really trying to accomplish, we can give another suggestion.